Is there a replacement for gazebo_ros::Node in Gazebo Sim?
Migrating plugins from Gazebo Classic to Gazebo Sim, I'm trying to figure out how to replace gazebo_ros::Node which is used frequently in my plugins. Migration from Gazebo Classic: Plugins makes no mention of gazebo_ros::Node. I expected ros_gz to have a gazebo_ros::Node analog but I couldn't find one, unless I'm not understanding something since there are parts of it that do use rclcpp::Node.
node.hpp says it is a "Wrapper around an rclcpp::Node which ensures all instances share an executor." This seems like it would still be useful functionality in Gazebo Sim. Should I just use a plain rclcpp::Node now and manage its spinning myself? If I use the shared "gazebo" node that I can get from gazebo_ros::Node::Get(), is there a replacement for that?

This is more or less a duplicate of my previous question. There's a few thoughts there that might be relevant, but I did not receive answers. I didn't look further as I only needed to publish messages, and a node does not have to be spun for that.

There isn't an equivalent gazebo_ros::Node::Get() function offered by ros_gz. The ros_gz bridge is launched as a separate ros node through a launch file or cmd line. As commented above, you can choose to embed a ROS 2 node in your gazebo system (instead of using ros_gz). I don't know if there are any best practices for how to spin your node in the gazebo system. It also mainly it depends on what you're using the node for, e.g. doing one-off service requests, subscribing to msgs, or publishing, etc

The "previous question" posted by @JRTG was useful. Unfortunately, it has been deleted and can no longer be read. I can't find clear instructions on how to help it get restored. I probably would have commented on it eventually, but the code it helped me with is large and still not compiling for unrelated reasons.

Heh :-) What are the odds to link to a question, only to have it deleted by the community bot a few days later....  I could still access the question, posted it here as an answer (for reference), as I think it should work that way. There's a few details (e.g. spin_some() vs spin_all() but given my current knowledge, I'm fairly sure those don't matter very much.

In the ROSCon 2022 presentation on ROS 2 and Gazebo Integration Best Practices, one of the proposed options is to embed a ROS 2 node into a Gazebo Sim System.
The slides propose to add following section in Configure():
if(!rclcpp::ok()) {
  rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);
}

and then to create a node and publisher/subscriber/etc as required.
This works for publishing messages, but for subscriptions, timers, services, etc., it is also necessary to spin the node.
I think this could work by:

Also creating an Executor in the Configure() step,

Adding the node to it,

Calling executor_.spin_some() in the preUpdate() step, or alternatively spin_once() or spin_all(),

Those functions optionally take a time-out value. I assume in many case this is not relevant as the node will not be doing extensive work (e.g. only publishing and subscribing to some data), but it is probably best to specify a time-out.


I would be inclined to go with a spin_all() as that makes sure everything gets processed, but I am not sure if that is best-practice.
And then to stop the ROS node at the end, I think the following is needed in the system plugin's destructor:
executor_.cancel();
rclcpp::shutdown();

